# In which cases does "Select count(*)" vs "Select count(*) AS" in PostgreSQL give different results?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have a table where running the following two commands gives me a different result:

```
SELECT count(*) AS result_count FROM test_table; 
SELECT count(*) FROM test_table;
```

The first command returns the correct number or rows (about 1 million) and the second command returns an incorrect number of rows(about 50K). The queries are run from within pgadmin.

Does anyone know why this happens? On other tables that I tested the results are consistent and correct.

For this particular table even this command gives me the correct amount of rows:

```
SELECT reltuples::bigint FROM pg_class where relname='test_table';
```

The table has 3 columns, a serial id (integer), a timestamp without timezone and a numeric value.

Thanks in advance for any information,
Michalis

Comment: I don't believe it. Please add the query plans to your question. Plus the table definition.

Comment: @joop : I retried the queries today after restarting my pc and the results are consistent and correct on all tables. I was wondering if the issue I was getting could be a result of some corruption, but now I am also more inclined to believe that it was human error. Thanks for taking the time to reply. As I am new to stackoverflow (as a member) could you let me know if I should delete this post or keep it open?

Comment: Without additional information, this problem cannot be solved (the obvious reason is that the queries were performed in different databases or schemas) . WRT closing: whatever suits you.

Answer (score 0):

My original question might be invalid as I have not been able to reproduce the issue after restarting my PC the next day.